# How to create something like onSetListener for an AtomicReference in Android

Tags: java, android

I have this in my Application class:

```
public AtomicReference<List<Story>> stories;
```

A few threads and a few adapters are using these stories.

I want to add something like onSetListener to this AtomicReference, so that
every time `.set()` is called on this AtomicReference, I get a notification (in order to notify all adapters currently using those stories to call notifyDataSetChnaged();

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use Observer pattern here, You can add a set of observers listening for the change in the value and then notifying the change to the observers. FYI http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm. Or you can use local broadcast manager to obtain the same.

Comment: I was thinking about using GreenRobot's EventBus to do the notification, but I was wondering how to observe the change on the AtomicReference itself. Maybe wrap an object around it or something>

Comment: Since it is a list if you want to listen for all the changes that happen to the list you can extend the ArrayList class and in all the public methods notify the observers about the change.